# JPA @OneToMany relationship to @Embedded class used as @Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations

I have a problem (and I'm not sure if it is possible) whit an association and an embedded id using JPA...

I have a `Person` class with it's id:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonCode personCode;
    private String name;

    @Embeddable
    public static class PersonCode{
        private String code;
    }
}
```

And then I would like to create a class `Company` with the association:

```
@Entity
public class Company{
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<PersonCode> employees;
}
```

But I have this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: example.domain.Company.employees[example.domain.Person$PersonCode]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An association must be between two entities. The company should have a `List<Person>`.

BTW, you make it much harder than necessary. Just use

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    private String code;

    private String name;
}
```

There's no reason to wrap a single field into an embeddable class.

Comment: Due to some DDD reccomendation I was trying to figure out how to manage the relationship of two entities without that both aren't responsible for the other...So if it was possible to use a single ID class to make the relationship it was easy to achieve...so thank you!